# WordPress - How to alphabetically order jQuery AutoComplete search suggestion results, prioritizing first character, then second etc.?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQueryUI AutoComplete with WordPress to fetch terms of a custom taxonomy as a user types in a search box.

I have a lot of sports brands as custom taxonomy terms, so, for example, the term `Adidas` can have many subterms. Now when I type `a`, it displays...

- `Adidas`
- `Adidas Shoes`
- `Adidas Socks`
- etc...

...causing the other brands to get in the dark. So, when I type `a`, I would like the results to show as follows...

- `Adidas`
- `Amphipod`
- `Asics`
- etc...

...until I continue typing `ad`, and only then should the `Adidas` results with the subterms appear, like in the first example. Is this possible to accomplish? Is jQueryUI AutoComplete able to order the results for me like this, or do I need to sort them on the server side with a PHP function like `sort`, `usort` etc.? I've tried to write a few different PHP sort functions to no avail so far, but I really have no idea right now.

This is the code I have right now:

**autocomplete.js**

```
$(function() {
    var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=my_search";
    $('.search-field').autocomplete({
        source: url,                
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 2,
        sortResults: true
    })
});
```

**functions.php (WordPress)**

```
function my_search()
{
    $args = array(
        'search'                => strtolower($_GET['term']),
        'taxonomy'              => array('suggestion_string'),
        'orderby'               => 'name',
        'order'                 => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'            => false,
        'number'                => 10,
    );
    $search_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
    $results = array( );
    if ( $search_query->get_terms() ) {
        foreach($search_query->get_terms() as $term) { 
            $results[] = array(
                'label' => $term->name,
            );
        }
    }
    else {

    }

    // Tried to write a few different sort functions here to no avail, like:
    sort($results);

    $data = json_encode($results);
    echo html_entity_decode( $data );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search', 'my_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search', 'my_search' );
```

Comment: Add your code here and let us know what is the issue, refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how you can ask question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is possible my friend you just have to code it as you wish. You can achieve what you want on the server side as well as on the client side, in this case I would recommend the server side though.

If you do not want autocomplete show subcategories just do not deliver those. Either you eliminate names starting with the same word first or you exclude subcategories. Here is my code for you for the first possibility:

```
function my_search()
{
    $args = array(
        'search'                => strtolower($_GET['term']),
        'taxonomy'              => array('suggestion_string'),
        'orderby'               => 'name',
        'order'                 => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'            => false,
        'number'                => 10,
    );
    $search_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
    $results = array( );
    if ( $search_query->get_terms() ) {
        foreach($search_query->get_terms() as $term) { 
            $results[] = array(
                'label' => $term->name,
            );
        }
    }
    else {

    }

    $filtered = [];
    $existing = [];
    if(strlen($_GET['term'])<2) {
         foreach($results as $term) {
              $first_word = explode(" ",$term["label"])[0];
              if(!in_array($first_word,$existing) {
                    array_push($existing,$first_word);
                    $filtered[] = $term;
              }
         }
    } else {
         $filtered = $results;
    }

    $data = json_encode($results);
    echo html_entity_decode( $data );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search', 'my_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search', 'my_search' );
```